# Can't toggle from right to left Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two icons (Bootstraps Glyphicon) which are places as

1 : Menu Which as left of screen
   2 : Gift which is at the right of the screen.

When Clicked on `Menu` the toggle appears from `Left to Right`. This works fine.
But when the `Gift` is clicked it appears in some weird position as shown in the image with the name `Suraj Palwe` *This is at left part of the image*. I want this to appear from right of the screen to moving towards the left as per the width of `div`.

This is the image how it looks.[image]
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surajpalwe/0efpcxaa/)

This is the what I have written in my code

`style`

```
.slide_birthday_click{
          margin-top: 2%;
          padding: 5px;

          background: grey;
          height: auto;
          display:none;
          position:absolute;
          z-index: 5;
          float: right;
        }
```

`in html body`

```
<div class="slide_birthday_click">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>Suraj Palwe</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" style="float:right;" id="today_birthdays"></span>
```

`The Jquery Part`

```
$("#today_birthdays").click(function(){
        $(".slide_birthday_click").toggle("slide",{direction:'right'},2000);
      });
```

I want that Block Which contains the word `Suraj Palwe` to right of the screen as it toggles from `right to left`.

[image: This is the snap shot of js fiddle]

**I am not getting where I am doing wrong in my code**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please add your code to jsfiddle and paste the link here

Comment: try this .

$("#today_birthdays").click(function(){
        $(".slide_birthday_click").toggle("ease");
      });

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar Nope this still gets from left side .I want it from right side

Comment: follow this link ....

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: The fiddle does nothing.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me, i don't know why. But i have checked this code , try this $(".slide_birthday_click").hide(0).delay(0).toggle('slide', {
               direction: 'right'
           }, 1000);

Comment: Did you load jquery-ui?

Comment: @dingo_d both the `cdn` are linked css aw well as js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay This is how I solved my problem. One thing was missing in it!

> Just added **right:0;** to the css file

```
.slide_birthday_click{
      margin-top: 2%;
      padding: 5px;
      background: grey;
      height: auto;
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      z-index: 5;
      float: right;
      right: 0;
    }
```

Thanks to all!

This is the link to [JS Fiddle Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/surajpalwe/0efpcxaa/10/)

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$("#today_birthdays").delay(200).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1500);
```

Comment: Nope this still comes from left side

Comment: Look at the changes... and edit for your preferences